# We have two list need to filter second list compare with first list using spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
List1 = (" data center best practice design","essentials advantage","technical and business solution")  
List2 = ("data center best","essentials","data","data center","capture","mssp umbrella")
```

output using Spark-scala:

```
List_output = ("data center best","essentials","data","data center")
```

Comment: can u pls elaborate your problem..like how do u need to filter seconds list.

Comment: As shown list1 and list2, List1 have some strings, List2 have some strings. I need to filter list2 if list2 string match the part of list1 string. Using spark with scala

Comment: if one single string is matched from list2 to list1..then u call it a match ..right

Comment: Yes, but list2 string is substring of list1.

Comment: sample data : List1 = (" data center best practice design","essentials advantage","technical and business solution")
List2 = ("data center best","essentials","data","data center","capture","mssp umbrella") OUTPUT using Spark-scala: List_output = ("data center best","essentials","data","data center")

Comment: input_List1 = (" data center best practice design","essentials advantage","technical and business solution")

Comment: input_List2 = ("data center best","essentials","data","data center","capture","mssp umbrella")

Comment: List_output = ("data center best","essentials","data","data center")

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following.

```
val list_output = parentList filter (childList.toSet)
```

Answer (score 0):

val List_output = List2.filter( p => List1.exists(e => e.matches(s"$p .*")))